# Deleting old list and showing new list

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

Old and New Records are shown together.

I add content to the DB and it is displayed as soon it is added (button event listener). But when the content is shown it is shown like-

- Content1
- Content2

***(This is the old content list)***

- Content1
- Content2
- Content3

The page shows Content 1-2 and Content 1-3.

It should only show -

- Content1
- Content2
- Content3

***This is the correct list and the desired output.***

The correct list is shown when I refresh the page and the list is fetched from the DB itself.

Code-

```
function showData() {



database.on("value", function (snapshot) {



    var listings = document.getElementsByClassName("contentClass");
    for (var j = listings.length; j < 0; j++) {
        listings[j].remove();
    }

    var dbData = snapshot.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(dbData);
    keys = keys.reverse();

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {

        var k = keys[i];
        var textContent = dbData[k].content;
        var timeContent = dbData[k].time;
        var dateContent = dbData[k].date;

        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.classList.add("contentClass");
        var something = `
            <div class="dataDiv">
            ${textContent + "<br />" + timeContent + "<br />" + dateContent}
            </div>
        ` ;

        newDiv.innerHTML = something;
        content.appendChild(newDiv);

    }

})


}

showData();
```

How do I make sure the old list is not generated whenever I add new content and display it on my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd enclose it in a wrapper and update the wrapper each time.

```
(function showData() {

  database.on("value", function (snapshot) {
    const wrapper = document.getElementsByID("wrapper");
    wrapper.innerHTML = '';

    var dbData = snapshot.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(dbData);
    keys = keys.reverse();

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      var k = keys[i];
      var textContent = dbData[k].content;
      var timeContent = dbData[k].time;
      var dateContent = dbData[k].date;

      var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      newDiv.classList.add("contentClass");
      var something = `<div class="dataDiv">${textContent + "<br />" + timeContent + "<br />" + dateContent}</div>` ;

      newDiv.innerHTML = something;
      wrapper.appendChild(newDiv);
    }

  });

})();
```

Comment: I tried that too, but still not getting the desired output.

Comment: this worked exactly as I wanted it to , but can you tell what was wrong in my approach.

Comment: Firstly, I am not sure if it removed the individual listings. Secondly, I don't know what the variable content means there.

Comment: It basically holds all the elements with the classname and when its lopped it should remove all the elements having the same class name.